# Are private constants possible in PHP?

Tags: php, constants, private

PHP does not allow

```
class Foo
{
    private const my_private_const;
```

but of course allows

```
const my_const;
```

So in effect constants are global because I can access `my_const` anywhere using `Foo::my_const`

Is there a way to make private constants?

Comment: if it's a constant value, would it matter if its private or not?

Comment: you can define class constants that belong to a class http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: @Hajo - how? private const produces an error.

Comment: @Hajo: Incorrect. As TheAllFoo mentioned, a constant can be referred to anywhere using `Class::CONSTANT`.

Comment: @TheAllFoo seems class constants are not changeable from public to something else, sorry

Comment: Where is the dependency injection advocate when you need one?

Comment: i wonder why a private or proctected attribute / property is not usable in his case

Comment: I wanted to do it for consistencies ( this is how I do it in javaScript ) sake and for the sake of encapsulation and dependency injection as good programming practice, i.e. I wanted to inject my globals, not just access them

Comment: @ChasingDeath: It matters: you don't want to expose publicly a constant used only by internal (private or protected) members.

Comment: @Hajo: Properties can be modified. They are also very different from the Zend Engine standpoint: they are stored in totally different symbol tables, with constants being stored in a (somewhat) read-only area of memory. Also, constants can be retrieved using a single opcode while properties require at least two.

Comment: It might be useful to have private constants when generating doxygen documentation (that is, when you're telling doxygen not to expose private class members).

Comment: can't you just define a constant in a private method and give it out

Comment: Now its possible in PHP 7.1.0 (http://php.net/archive/2016.php#id2016-12-01-3)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The answer is a simple "no".  PHP doesn't support this concept.  The best you can do is a `private static` variable in the class, which isn't as good of course because it's not readonly.  But you just have to work around it.

***Edit***

Your question got me thinking - here's something I've never tried, but might work. Put another way "this is untested".  But say you wanted a "private constant" called `FOO`:

```
// "Constant" definitions
private function __get($constName){
    // Null for non-defined "constants"
    $val = null;

    switch($constName){
        case 'FOO':
            $val = 'MY CONSTANT UNCHANGEABLE VALUE';
            break;
        case 'BAR':
            $val = 'MY OTHER CONSTANT VALUE';
            break;
    }

    return $val;
}
```

Of course your syntax would look a bit odd:

```
// Retrieve the "constant"
$foo = $this->FOO;
```

...but at least this wouldn't work:

```
$this->FOO = 'illegal!';
```

Maybe something worth trying?

Cheers

Comment: This is an awesome suggestion... I will most definitely use it! Thanks for sharing. Another option is to make all variables private and protected, then create a function like this one to filter which variables can be changed and which are forced to be read-only.. See this I just published! http://www.designersgate.com/blogs/?p=187

Comment: Unfortunately the magic private getter won't work as PHP wants __get with public visibility.

Comment: Basically the concept of "runtime defined constants". The implemetation is a cool idea. I like it. And `$this->FOO` is not odd, if PHP would support "constants as variables" like Java - then it would be the proper OOP access to a class constant.

Comment: I modified your code a bit, added final to class and blocked modification by using magic set. see http://3v4l.org/UgEEm

Comment: @Jens-AndréKoch Glad you like. The addition of preventing setting using `__set` is a great one, please feel free to add it to the answer if you feel so inclined.

Comment: @Madbreaks, is marcosdsanchez's comment true?

Comment: the private and private static function approach: private static function cX() { return "x"; }  does not work in the context: private static $mapper = array(self::cX() => "abc123",....); however the following does work: const cX = "x"; private static $mapper = array(self::cX => "abc123",....); ...so there really is no equivalent substitute for private constants. Bring on PHP 7.1!

Answer (score 157):

Folks! [PHP 7.1.0 has been released](http://php.net/archive/2016.php#id2016-12-01-3)

Now it's possible to have visibility modifiers with class constants.

```
<?php
class Foo {
    // As of PHP 7.1.0
    public const BAR = 'bar';
    private const BAZ = 'baz';
}
echo Foo::BAR, PHP_EOL;
echo Foo::BAZ, PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Output of the above example in PHP 7.1:

```
bar

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private const Foo::BAZ in …
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer now

Answer (score 32):

Note, that visibility modifiers for class constants have been added in PHP 7.1.

RFC: [Support Class Constant Visibility](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_const_visibility)

Answer (score 7):

A simplified version of @Madbreaks' workaround: write a private static function that returns the value of your private "constant":

```
private static function MY_CONSTANT() {
    return "constant string";
}
```

Usage:

```
public static function DoStuff() {
    echo self::MY_CONSTANT();
}
```