# Check if a class constant exists

Tags: php, constants

How can I check if a constant is defined in a PHP class?

```
class Foo {
    const BAR = 1;
}
```

Is there something like `property_exists()` or `method_exists()` for class constants? Or can I just use `defined("Foo::BAR")`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956401/can-i-get-consts-defined-on-a-php-class

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yes, just use the class name in front of the constant name:

```php
defined('SomeNamespace\SomeClass::CHECKED_CONSTANT');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php#106287

Comment: Remember also to add any namespace to the string, aka: defined('my\name\space\ClassName\property')

Comment: It is useful to know that you can use `constant('SomeNamespace\SomeClass::CHECKED_CONSTANT')` to get its value

Answer (score 87):

You can check if a constant is defined with the code below:

```
<?php
if(defined('className::CONSTANT_NAME')){
  //defined
}else{
  //not defined
}
```

Comment: and `constant('className::CONSTANT_NAME')` to retrieve it.

Comment: ```className``` needs to be fully-qualified. Usually I do ```$class = get_class($obj); echo defined("$class::CONSTANT_NAME"));```. For more complex cases is better to use ```ReflectionClass```.

Comment: Also, from *PHP >= 7.1.0* there you can also use ```new \ReflectionClassConstant($class, 'CONSTANT_NAME');``` and ```try``` to ```catch``` an eventual ```ReflectionException``` in case the constant doesn't exist on the class. More complex checking, but not less correct; ```if/else``` is just replaced by a ```try/catch``` depending on the developer preferences or style.

Comment: Using late static binding you can use `if (defined(static::class . '::CONSTANT')) { $value = static::CONSTANT; } else { throw \RuntimeException('Class '.static::class.' needs constant CONTANT'); }`.

Comment: The late static binding example can be shortened even further to just: `defined('static::CONSTANT')`

Answer (score 21):

## You have 3 ways to do it:

## *defined()*

#### [PHP >= 4 - most retro-compatible way]

```
$class_name = get_class($object); // remember to provide a fully-qualified class name
$constant = "$class_name::CONSTANT_NAME";
$constant_value = defined($constant) ? $constant : null;
```

**Note**: using `defined()` on a [*private constant* (possible from PHP7.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40933237/3088045) will throw error: *"Cannot access private const"*. While using `ReflectionClass` or `ReflectionClassConstant` will work.

## *ReflectionClass*

#### [PHP >= 5]

```
$class_reflex = new \ReflectionClass($object);
$class_constants = $class_reflex->getConstants();
if (array_key_exists('CONSTANT_NAME', $class_constants)) {
    $constant_value = $class_constants['CONSTANT_NAME'];
} else {
    $constant_value = null;
}
```

## *ReflectionClassConstant*

#### [PHP >= 7.1.0]

```
$class_name = get_class($object); // fully-qualified class name
try {
    $constant_reflex = new \ReflectionClassConstant($class_name, 'CONSTANT_NAME');
    $constant_value = $constant_reflex->getValue();
} catch (\ReflectionException $e) {
    $constant_value = null;
}
```

There is no real better way. Depends on your needs and use case.

Comment: Your second example (PHP >= 5), the syntax is incorrect. `$class_constants)I{` should be `$class_constants)){`

Comment: Note that `defined()` private note is NOT true for `Trait` trait CAN access private stuff, therefore it can also test and access the constant. (works this way from 7.1 up to 8.1) - https://3v4l.org/NQ1f8 also note you can just do `defined("self::CONSTANT")` (note the quotes `"`)

Answer (score 11):

You can use that function:

```
function constant_exists($class, $name){
    if(is_string($class)){
        return defined("$class::$name");
    } else if(is_object($class)){
        return defined(get_class($class)."::$name");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or alternative version using [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/class.reflectionclass.php)

```
function constant_exists($class, $name) {
    if(is_object($class) || is_string($class)){
        $reflect = new ReflectionClass($class);
        return array_key_exists($name, $reflect->getConstants());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you need to check if constant value exists as one of class constant *values*, use second example with Reflection class, only change `array_key_exists` to `in_array`.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried this:

```
$constants = new \ReflectionClass(App\Namespace\ClassName::class);
if ($constants->getConstant('CONSTANT_NAME')){
    // Do this
} else {
    // Do that
}
```

And it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with inheritance and you want to check if a constant is defined at the point where you want to access it at runtime, you can use late static binding (since PHP 5.3).

```
$reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass(static::class);

if (!array_key_exists('MY_CONST', $reflectionClass->getConstants())){
    throw new \LogicException('You must define the constant MY_CONST in the concrete class');
}
```

This can be used as a workaround to make sure a concrete class defines a constant needed elsewhere along the class hierarchy. Obviously, we need to keep in mind the caveat that this is done at run time. But if you add this check in the tests in your CI pipeline it's a good enough workaround.